# gooey module not installing correctly

Tags: python, windows, pip

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install Gooey
Collecting Gooey
  Using cached Gooey-0.9.2.3.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Haeshan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build- 5waer38m\Gooey\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    version = __import__('gooey').__version__
  File "C:\Users\Haeshan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-5waer38m\Gooey\gooey\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gooey.python_bindings.gooey_decorator import Gooey
  File "C:\Users\Haeshan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-5waer38m\Gooey\gooey\python_bindings\gooey_decorator.py", line 54
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in   
C:\Users\Haeshan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-5waer38m\Gooey\
```

this error is appearing when I try to install the Gooey module for python, any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using Python 3.4 but Gooey only supports Python 2:

https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey/issues/65

http://python3porting.com/differences.html#except

---

**Update Jan 2018:** The Gooey project now supports Python 3 https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey